# Clickable DIVs using jQuery hide()

Tags: html, hide, jquery

I have a working click-able, collapsible div script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-content").hide();
    $(".byline").click(function() {
        $(".toggle-content").hide();
        $(this).next(".toggle-content").slideToggle(500);   
    });
});
```

It started out just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-content").hide();
    $(".byline").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".toggle-content").slideToggle(500);   
    });
});
```

Thsi second example worked nicely, but it made it so the user could open all the `div`s and this made the page too tall.  I added the `hide()` function, but now it's causing this other issue.

I would like to add functionality that when each `div` is clicked again, it actually closes it (hides it).  Then, all `div`s would be closed (hidden) at this point.  Currently, one `div` is always open (visible).  I want both functions if possible...

I'm using accordion elsewhere (I know this could be used here) but I kind of need to get this going quickly so I'm not trying to implement the simpler script here.  If I could just find a fix using the existing script, I'd be stoked.

**EDIT**

I've edited the fiddle to show the improved fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicorellius/gsDVS/

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the associated HTML for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It will ignore hiding the content related to the clicked element and will slideToggle that div accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-content").hide();
    $(".byline").click(function() {
        var $next= $(this).next(".toggle-content");
        $(".toggle-content").not($next).hide();
        $next.slideToggle(500);   
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great - and it works... +1  Quick question, if I could...  When I click the non-this `div` it opens and the others close, but in a quick, almost jerking fashion.  Is there a way to control the closing easing too?  In other words, when I click the `this-div` it closes with the same smoothness that it opened with (`value = 500`).  I will accept your answer too ;-)

Comment: can use `slideUp()` instead of `hide()`. `hide()` is immmediate